# Наблюдение за буфером обмена

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi

Нужно, чтобы код, который проверяет буфер обмена, работал постоянно. Сейчас он у меня срабатывает только по нажатию на кнопку. Как это можно организовать ?

```
 int i = 0;
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.A)
            {
                stroka = Clipboard.GetText();

                for (i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (array[i] == "")
                    {
                        array[i] = stroka;
                        break;
                    }
                    else if (array[9] != "")
                    {
                       DialogResult dr = MessageBox.Show("Ошибка. Буфер переполнен. Хотите очистить буфер ?","Предупреждение",MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel);
                       if (dr == DialogResult.OK)
                       {
                           for (i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
                           {
                               array[i] = "";
                           }
                       }
                        break;
                    }

                }
            }

                if (e.KeyCode == Keys.D0)
                {
                    textBox3.Text = array[0];
                }
                if (e.KeyCode == Keys.D1)
                {
                    textBox3.Text = array[1];
                }
                if (e.KeyCode == Keys.D2)
                {
                    textBox3.Text = array[2];
                }
                if (e.KeyCode == Keys.D3)
                {
                    textBox3.Text = array[3];
                }
                if (e.KeyCode == Keys.D4)
                {
                    textBox3.Text = array[4];
                }
                if (e.KeyCode == Keys.D5)
                {
                    textBox3.Text = array[5];
                }
                if (e.KeyCode == Keys.D6)
                {
                    textBox3.Text = array[6];
                }
                if (e.KeyCode == Keys.D7)
                {
                    textBox3.Text = array[7];
                }
                if (e.KeyCode == Keys.D8)
                {
                    textBox3.Text = array[8];
                }
                if (e.KeyCode == Keys.D9)
                {
                    textBox3.Text = array[9];
                }
```

Копируется что-то в буфер, нажимается кнопка А и из буфера значение заносится в массив, потом снова копируется значение, нажимается А и значение копируется в массив на позицию i+1. А мне нужно, чтобы это происходило без нажатия на кнопку А. Бесконечным циклом не вышло:программа просто не запускается.

Comment: Какой код, какой буфер, какая кнопка ... в вопросе катастрофически не хватает деталей.

Comment: +1 к предыдущему комментарию, но скрытый медиум подсказывает мне, что вам нужен простой таймер, который через заданный интервал времени будет проверять буфер. Почитайте про компонент таймер WinForms на MSDN, там даже примеры есть, или поищите тут, тема поднималась неоднократно, тут про все дотнетовские таймеры, хотя бы по одному вопросу с ответом да найдется.

Comment: Понял, спасибо.

Comment: только не забывайте сбрасывать стояние буфера после обработки, а то я уже предвижу следующий вопрос =) и добавте недостающую информацию в текущий

Comment: У меня записывается текущее состояние буфера в 2 переменные. В первую переменную сразу при копировании, во вторую после добавления в массив. И потом при следующем копировании сравниваю эти переменные. В первой хранится новое значение буфера, во второй переменной старое.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Конечно, можно запустить бесконечный цикл где-нибудь в отдельном потоке, но на мой взгляд такое решение как минимум некорректно. Windows предоставляет возможность отслеживать изменения буфера обмена - т.е., изменения будут отслеживаться и обрабатываться в реальном времени. Как я понимаю, вас интересует именно это, а не `while (true)` :)

В [статье за авторством Тома Арчера](http://www.codeguru.com/columns/dotnettips/article.php/c7315/Monitoring-Clipboard-Activity-in-C.htm) рассказывается, как организовать отслеживание в WinForms. Приведу краткое переложение раздела "Пошаговые инструкции" (с переводом и некоторыми изменениями в коде).

---

### 1

Необходимо вызвать пару функций из библиотеки Win32 —`SetClipboardViewer`, `ChangeClipboardChain`, и `SendMessage` Для того, чтобы сделать это в приложении .NET, необходимо импортировать их, используя атрибут `DllImport`. В примере ниже эти функции импортируются в приложение WinForms:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
...
public partial class frmMain : Form
{
  [DllImport("User32.dll")]
  protected static extern int
            SetClipboardViewer(int hWndNewViewer);
  [DllImport("User32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]
  public static extern bool
         ChangeClipboardChain(IntPtr hWndRemove,
                              IntPtr hWndNewNext);
  [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]
  public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hwnd, int wMsg,
                                       IntPtr wParam,
                                       IntPtr lParam);
  ...
```

### 2

Определим член класса для помещения текущего окна в цепь уведомлений буфера
*Оригинальный текст: Define a class member to hold the current first window in the Clipboard notification chain:*

```
public partial class frmMain : Form
    {
        ...
        IntPtr nextClipboardViewer;
```

### 3

Вызовем функцию `SetClipboardViewer`. В примере она вызывается в конструкторе формы:

```
public frmMain()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    nextClipboardViewer = (IntPtr)SetClipboardViewer((int)
            this.Handle);
}
```

### 4

Внутри класса `frmMain` переопределим метод `WndProc`.
В примере обрабатываются только два сообщения: `WM_DRAWCLIPBOARD` и `WM_CHANGECBCHAIN`.

- В коде, обрабатывающем `WM_DRAWCLIPBOARD`, вызывается пользовательский метод `DisplayClipboardData()`, который выводит содержимое буфера; затем то же сообщение передаётся следующему в цепи окну.
- В коде, обрабатывающем `WM_CHANGECBCHAIN`, проверяется, является ли окно, удалённое из цепи буфера, следующим (по отношению к текущему). Если да,  `nextClipboardViewer` присваивается окно, следующее за удалённым.

  `protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)`

  ```
  {

          const int WM_DRAWCLIPBOARD = 0x308;
          const int WM_CHANGECBCHAIN = 0x030D;

      switch (m.Msg)
      {
          case WM_DRAWCLIPBOARD:
              DisplayClipboardData();
              SendMessage(nextClipboardViewer, m.Msg, m.WParam,
                            m.LParam);
              break;

          case WM_CHANGECBCHAIN:
              if (m.WParam == nextClipboardViewer)
                  nextClipboardViewer = m.LParam;
              else
                  SendMessage(nextClipboardViewer, m.Msg, m.WParam,
                                   m.LParam);
              break;

          default:
              base.WndProc(ref m);
              break;
      }
  }
  ```

### 5

Наконец, окно удаляется из цепи буфера, когда .NET Runtime вызывает метод `Dispose` класса `frmMain`

```
protected override void Dispose( bool disposing )
{
  ChangeClipboardChain(this.Handle, nextClipboardViewer);
  ...
```

---

В инструкции не описан, собственно, метод `DisplayClipboardData`. У меня он выглядит так:

```
private void DisplayClipboardData()
{
    txtBox.Text = Clipboard.GetText();
}
```

Т.е., в текстовое поле на форме просто выводится текст из буфера. В вашем случае нужно вставить обработку массива.

На всякий случай, полный листинг того, что вышло у меня:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace clipborad
{
    public partial class frmMain : Form
    {
        Random r = new Random();

        [DllImport("User32.dll")]
        protected static extern int
          SetClipboardViewer(int hWndNewViewer);
        [DllImport("User32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public static extern bool
               ChangeClipboardChain(IntPtr hWndRemove,
                                    IntPtr hWndNewNext);
        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hwnd, int wMsg,
                                             IntPtr wParam,
                                             IntPtr lParam);

        IntPtr nextClipboardViewer;

        public frmMain()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            nextClipboardViewer = (IntPtr)SetClipboardViewer((int)
                         this.Handle);
        }

        protected override void WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)
        {
            // defined in winuser.h
            const int WM_DRAWCLIPBOARD = 0x308;
            const int WM_CHANGECBCHAIN = 0x030D;

            switch (m.Msg)
            {
                case WM_DRAWCLIPBOARD:
                    DisplayClipboardData();
                    SendMessage(nextClipboardViewer, m.Msg, m.WParam,
                                  m.LParam);
                    break;

                case WM_CHANGECBCHAIN:
                    if (m.WParam == nextClipboardViewer)
                        nextClipboardViewer = m.LParam;
                    else
                        SendMessage(nextClipboardViewer, m.Msg, m.WParam,
                                         m.LParam);
                    break;

                default:
                    base.WndProc(ref m);
                    break;
            }
        }

        private void DisplayClipboardData()
        {
            txtBox.Text = Clipboard.GetText();
        }
    }
}
```

Плюс не забываем добавить строку `ChangeClipboardChain(this.Handle, nextClipboardViewer);` в метод `Dispose` в файле `frmMain.Designer.cs`

Код компилируется и прекрасно работает в Win10 x64. Текст из буфера вставляется в текстовое поле сразу после копирования, никаких кнопок дополнительно нажимать не надо