# Win32 API. Скопировать выделенный текст из другого приложения

Tags: c#, wpf, winapi

Необходимо передать выделенный текст из любого приложения по комбинации клавиш.
Как я предполагал, это доллжно выглядеть? Я нажимаю, alt+shift+j. Выделенный текст попадает в буфер. Потом программа должна достать оттуда текст. Вопрос: как поместить текст в буфер?
Пытался сделать это через WM_COPY и через симуляцию нажатия Ctrl-C, чтобы текст попал в буфер обмена, но все тщетно. Программа вытягивает то, что было до этого в буфере.
С WinAPI практически не знаком, поэтому буду рад, если вы напишете подробное решение.

```cs
private IntPtr _windowHandle;
private HwndSource _source;

protected override void OnSourceInitialized(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnSourceInitialized(e);

    _windowHandle = new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle;
    _source = HwndSource.FromHwnd(_windowHandle);
    _source.AddHook(HwndHook);

    RegisterHotKey(_windowHandle, HOTKEY_ID, MOD_ALT + MOD_SHIFT, VK_J); //ALT + SHIFT + J

}

private IntPtr HwndHook(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
{
    const int WM_HOTKEY = 0x0312;
    switch (msg)
    {
        case WM_HOTKEY:
            switch (wParam.ToInt32())
            {
                case HOTKEY_ID:
                    int vkey = (((int)lParam >> 16) & 0xFFFF);
                    if (vkey == VK_J)
                    {
                        string word = GetSelectedText();
                        MessageBox.Show(word);
                    }
                    handled = true;
                    break;
            }
            break;
    }
    return IntPtr.Zero;
}

protected override void OnClosed(EventArgs e)
{
    _source.RemoveHook(HwndHook);
    UnregisterHotKey(_windowHandle, HOTKEY_ID);
    base.OnClosed(e);
}

private string GetSelectedText()
{
    Type whatDoesContainClipboard = null;
    object clipboardData = null;

    if (Clipboard.ContainsAudio())
    {
        whatDoesContainClipboard = typeof(Stream);
        clipboardData = Clipboard.GetAudioStream();
    }
    else if (Clipboard.ContainsImage())
    {
        whatDoesContainClipboard = typeof(BitmapSource);
        clipboardData = Clipboard.GetImage();
    }
    else if (Clipboard.ContainsText())
    {
        whatDoesContainClipboard = typeof(string);
        clipboardData = Clipboard.GetText();
    }


    int handle = GetForegroundWindow();
    int ProcessID;
    int SelectedThreadId = GetWindowThreadProcessId(handle, out ProcessID);
    int CurrentThreadId = GetCurrentThreadId();
    Process SelectedProcess = Process.GetProcessById(ProcessID);

    AttachThreadInput(SelectedThreadId, CurrentThreadId, true);
    IntPtr FocusedWindowEx = GetFocus();
    SendMessage(FocusedWindowEx, WM_COPY, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);

    IDataObject data = Clipboard.GetDataObject();
    string[] formats = data.GetFormats();

    var selectedText = "";
    if (formats.Contains<string>("System.String"))
        selectedText = (string)data.GetData("System.String");

    AttachThreadInput(SelectedThreadId, CurrentThreadId, false);


    if (whatDoesContainClipboard != null)
    {
        if (whatDoesContainClipboard == typeof(Stream))
            Clipboard.SetAudio((Stream)clipboardData);
        else if (whatDoesContainClipboard == typeof(BitmapSource))
            Clipboard.SetImage((BitmapSource)clipboardData);
        else if (whatDoesContainClipboard == typeof(string))
            Clipboard.SetText((string)clipboardData);
    }
    else
        Clipboard.Clear();

    return selectedText;
}

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern bool RegisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id, uint fsModifiers, uint vk);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern bool UnregisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern int GetForegroundWindow();

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern int GetWindowThreadProcessId(Int32 hWnd, out Int32 lpdwProcessId);

[DllImport("User32.dll")]
private static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
private static extern int GetCurrentThreadId();

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern int AttachThreadInput(int idAttach, int idAttachTo, bool fAttach);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern IntPtr GetFocus();

const int WM_COPY = 0x0301;

private const int HOTKEY_ID = 9000;

//Modifiers:
private const uint MOD_NONE = 0x0000; //(none)
private const uint MOD_ALT = 0x0001; //ALT
private const uint MOD_CONTROL = 0x0002; //CTRL
private const uint MOD_SHIFT = 0x0004; //SHIFT
private const uint MOD_WIN = 0x0008; //WINDOWS
private const uint VK_J = 0x4A;
```

Comment: [Поможет?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/589585/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0-%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0/589679#589679)

Comment: Не очень. Там смысл в отслеживании буфера, т.е. он реагирует на его обновление. Мне же надо, чтобы программа реагировала на горячие клавиши и сама добывала выделенный текст, не так важно через буфер или нет.

Comment: Так что вам мешает адаптировать пример: вставлять текст не автоматически, а по горячей клавише?

Comment: Я не увидел там, как мне получить текст. Там нет копирования выделенного текста в буфер. В это-то весь вопрос: как получить текст?

Comment: Там есть копирование выделенного текста в буфер - за это отвечает ОС. В примере пользовательского - только извлечение текста из буфера, вот так: `txtBox.Text = Clipboard.GetText();`

Comment: В применениее к вашему примеру - вам не нужно специально помещать что-то в буфер, достаточно просто скопировать. Слушатель может отслеживать буфер, и выбирать скопированное по какому-то ключевому признаку: например, по ключевому слову вначале скопированного текста

Comment: Суть приложения: добавлять неизвестные слова из любых текстов в список для последующего запоминания, поэтому ключевые слова не в кассу. Я посылал WM_COPY, но не сработала. Пытался сымитировать нажатие Ctrl-C, но тоже не взлетело. Я пытался найти какие функции могут скопировать текст в буфер, но не нашел.

Comment: Я так и не понял, почему вам не подходит монитор: он же вам наоборот упрощает задачу. Пользователь копирует любой текст в буфер, ваша программа, отслеживая буфер, парсит текст и запоминает незнакомые слова. Специально копировать ничего не надо - текст из любого источника копируется штатными средствами ОС

Comment: Потому что слова могут встретиться в любом месте и в любой момент я могу захотеть добавить слово. Это может случиться разово, может длиться какое-то время, но в перерывах между добавлением слов я скорее всего буду что-то копипастить, что никакого отношения к словам иметь не может.

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, в вопрос информацию о том, что это должно происходить исключительно по требованию пользователя, а то сейчас из вопроса следует как раз то, что отслеживание должно происходить при любом копировании

Comment: Вам нужно разделить задачу на несколько _отдельных_ вопросов: 1. как установить хук на горячие клавиши; 2. как получить активное окно; 3. как скопировать выделенный текст из чужого приложения; и т. п. На большинство из них есть ответы - воспользуйтесь поиском.